# How to include tabbed text on a beamer titlepage?

Tags: beamer, author, tabbing, tabto

The MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tabto}

\title{Title}
\author{Author \\
Text\\
%% INSERT TABBING HERE
}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{frame}
\textbf{Test 1}
\begin{tabbing}
This \= is a \= test. \\
H \> I \> !
\end{tabbing}

\textbf{Test 2}

This \tabto{3cm} is another one.

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

gives following result:

[image]

How can I enter tabbed text in the `\author` field (as indicated in the code)?

When substituting one of the two solutions shown on the second slide in the author field, I obtain the error

> ! Use of \begin doesn't match its definition.
> \beamer@andstripped ->Author \ Text\ \begin {tabbing} This = is a = test...

for `tabbing` and

> ! Undefined control sequence.
> \tabto ... count@ -4 \prevgraf \count@ \TTo@action \fi \endgroup \TTo@overlap...

for `tabto`.